# Exporting JSON to Excel in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, excel

I have gone through similar questions but haven't got any solution to the specific problem i have [here](http://jsfiddle.net/divm/gte215m6/).

I am trying to export it to excel and on opening the downloaded file i am getting the following message.

[image]

Plus on opening the excel file i see all column data in a single column separated by comma.

In fact the original code was for exporting it to a `.csv` and worked perfectly fine.but when i changed it to export as `.xls` the issue  arise.Please let me know where am i going wrong!

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/divm/gte215m6/) is the fiddle illustrating the problem

Comment: Have you tried this?: http://jordiburgos.com/post/2014/excellentexport-javascript-export-to-excel-csv.html

Comment: This kind of "faking CSV to seem XLS" works only with tabulation delimited CSV. See http://jsfiddle.net/gte215m6/1/. Using server side approaches which really can create Excel files would be better.